# Double integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{1} \sin(\pi \ y^3)dy\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In this integral i have tried some substitution and have changed the order of integration too but i couldn't solve this

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{1} \sin(\pi \ y^3)dy\ dx$$
any suggestion would be great

Thanks

Comment: $$\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{x}}^1[\ldots]\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1\int_0^{y^2}[\ldots]\,dx\,dy.$$

Comment: Thank you i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the graphs of the functions that describe the domain of integration:[image]
We can easily observe that the area can be also written as $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:0\le x\le y^2,0\le y\le1\}$, so the integral becomes:$$\int_0^1\int_{0}^{y^2}\sin(\pi y^3)dxdy=\int_0^1y^2\sin(\pi y^3)dy=-\dfrac{\cos(\pi y^3)}{3\pi}\Bigg|_0^1=\dfrac{1}{3\pi}+\dfrac{1}{3\pi}=\dfrac{2}{3\pi}.$$

Comment: It's the first time I use images in my answers. Do you know if I can change its dimensions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to change the order of integration is plausible. Specifically, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt x}^1 \sin(\pi y^3) dy dx  = \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} \sin(\pi y^3) dx dy = \int_0^1 y^2 \sin(\pi y^3) dy. 
$$
To see how to switch the limits, notice that the integration region is
$$ D = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1, \sqrt{x} \leq y \leq 1\rbrace = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1, x \leq y^2 \leq 1\rbrace $$
and the intersection point of the curve $ y = \sqrt{x} $ and $ x = 1 $ is (1,1). The result follows. You may convince yourself with the aid of other plotting software.

I'll leave the remaining integral to you, which can be solved by substitution of variable $ u = \pi y^3 $.